# Can this toad be approx 1cm long?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, amphibians

Recently the toad from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNv2prl0WOM) video has been identified as an American Toad inside [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amphibians/comments/jm5kki/what_is_the_species_of_this_viral_amphibian/) in Reddit. The [original video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIUSUDPmtm0) mentions it was filmed in White Clay Creek State Park, Newark, Delaware, USA.

[image: This is the toad]

Calculating the water's wavelength based on the sound yielded a value of 0.5mm. Using the image's ratios, the toad's length can be estimated. **The result was 7mm**. Yes, a toad being 7mm long.

The purpose of this question is to ask both if it effectively is a species of American Toad and if it's plausible for it to be 7mm long.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible) — photos **must** be uploaded (not links) — e.g. post stills captured from the video; 2) habitat information. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 